# Восстановление директории в linux

Tags: linux, debian, recovery

Подскажите как восстановить уделенную (через shift+del) директорию (внутри директории один файл) в debian?

### Пробовал такие утилиты как testdisk, photorec и ext4magic, всеони видят директорию как файл. Не могу разобраться почему.

Разобрался что это отдельная файловая система, но монтировать её не получается.

Comment: в линукс всё файл =)

Comment: https://losst.ru/vosstanovlenie-udalennyh-fajlov-linux

Comment: Все файл это понятно. Но директория восстанавливается как бинарник.

Comment: Вполне вероятно что никак

Comment: Неутешительно. Файл важный.

Comment: Надо было делать бэкапы. Линуксовые файловые системы не очень дружелюбны к попыткам восстановления

Comment: @Jazz Вы говорите что-то непонятное. 1) Причём тут "testdisk, photorec и ext4magic" ?! Если вы удалили файл в файловом браузере, то есть надежда, что он работает с корзинкой. Если командой *del* - то никак. 2) Что значит "видят директорию как файл" ?! Команда *ls -l* что выдаёт в первой позиции - 'd' или '-'?  Что значит "это отдельная файловая система" ?! А Вы её монтировали? Как? Или это флэшка и было автомонтирование? Но если это флэшка, то там (скорее всего) FAT32. И тогда восстановление возможно. Но если это раздел на HDD, то что вы на самом деле сделали?